# c# thread/query executing twice

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on some code that executes MDX queries against sql server analysis service. The MDX query is being executed twice on the same thread and I have no idea why. The query should only execute once

Below is some of the code. can anyone help please.

```
      private void Start_QueryWorkers()
    {            
           foreach (QueryThread th in _QueryWorkers)
           {
          SSASQuery q = new SSASQuery();                      
            q.QueryText = "SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[count] } ON COLUMNS FROM [cube]";                                 
            q.queryThread = th;              
            th.WorkerThread.RunWorkerAsync(q);
        }           
    } 

    private void QueryWorkerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SSASQuery q = e.Argument as SSASQuery;    
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q.QueryText, q.queryThread.conn); 
        OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
           rdr.Close();         
    }

      private void btnStartTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
            string strConnString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=SRV001"  + ";Initial Catalog=Cube_2015"  + ";";
         _QueryWorkers.Clear();
        {                
            QueryThread thread = new QueryThread(strConnString);          
             thread.WorkerThread = new BackgroundWorker();
              thread.WorkerThread.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(this.QueryWorkerThread_DoWork);                                   
               _QueryWorkers.Add(thread);       
        }                              
            Start_QueryWorkers();            
    }            
} 

class SSASQuery
{ 
    public string QueryText { get; set; }     
    public QueryThread queryThread { get; set; }         
}

class QueryThread
{
    public QueryThread(string connString)
    {
        this.connString = connString;
        conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();        
        queryList = new SortedList();
    }
    public SortedList queryList { get; set; }
    public string threadName { get; set; }
    public string connString { get; set; }
    public OleDbConnection conn;     
    public BackgroundWorker WorkerThread { get; set; }       
     }
```

}

Comment: BackgroundWorker isn't a thread, it's an obsolete abstraction over a thread. You gain nothing by trying to use it as if it were a Thread. It would be a lot easier to use PLINQ, Parallel.ForEach or ActionBlock<T> to execute each query in parallel and store the results wherever you want to store them

Comment: hi, ok thanks for the suggestion. anyway can you help with why the DoWork/BackgroundWorker is being executed twice in the above code

Comment: why are you using `for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)` if `numThreads=1`?

Comment: because numThreads can change. if set to one, should send 1 query..but right now sends 2 queries, if set to 2, should send 2 queries but now send 4...and so on

Comment: @user7195482 the code is *very* convoluted, precisely because you use BGW as if it were a thread. You haven't posted the code to QueryThread etc. One can only guess who executes, what, or when.

Comment: @user7195482 for example, why don't you use `ExecureReaderAsync` instead of creating multiple BGWs ?

Comment: hi, updated the code to simplfy the code and included query threadcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. code was ok, it was a problem in the connection string execting the query twice